# Why can we put the result of a GetComponent<Camera> in a Behaviour array but can't do GetComponent<Camera>(out behaviourArray[X])?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I wanted to know why this work :

```
Behaviour _BehaviourArray = new Behaviour[1];
BehaviourArray[0] = GetComponent<Camera>();
```

But not this :

```
Behaviour _BehaviourArray = new Behaviour[1];
TryGetComponent<Camera>(out BehaviourArray[0]);
```

Which is supposed (in my mind) to give the same result if both Camera components exists.

If someone can answer me it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The types do not match and thus the `out` parameter can't accept a variable of type `Behaviour`.

What you can do is write

```
Behaviour[] _BehaviourArray = new Behaviour[1];
TryGetComponent<Camera>(out Camera camera);
_BehaviourArray[0] = camera;
```

You may even wrap this in a method:

```
void GetComponentToArrayIndex<TComponent, TSpecificComponent>(TComponent[] array, int index) where TComponent : Component where TSpecificComponent : TComponent
{
    TryGetComponent<TSpecificComponent>(out TSpecificComponent component);
    array[index] = component;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Behaviour[] _BehaviourArray = new Behaviour[1];
GetComponentToArrayIndex<Camera>(_BehaviourArray, 0);
```

Those are just suggestions and untested code, but that's what I would try in your case.

---

I previously thought that Array indexers are similar to the indexer operator which boils down to two methods, but they do not seem to be like this. Thanks [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69885025/5593150) for the clarification.

Comment: Note that `Behaviour _BehaviourArray = new Behaviour[1];` still won't compile ;) And actually as soon as the types match correctly you [**can actually do it**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69885025/7111561)

Comment: An indexer in most types is a property getter/setter, **except for arrays** where array element indexing sites can by used in `ref` and `out` parameters. See @derHugo's answer.

Comment: I don't know why your post is downgraded, this is exactly what i wanted to know. I wanted specifically store a camera component in a behaviour array.

Comment: I thought about type matching and that this could work with arrays, but that's not what OP wanted. So my solution works fine. But I'll remove the stuff about properties as they seem to be wrong in this case. You always learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

Well actually you can do that though if the types in your code were correct:

```
public Camera[] _BehaviourArray;

private void Awake()
{
    _BehaviourArray = new Camera[1];
    TryGetComponent<Camera>(out _BehaviourArray[0]);

    Debug.Log(_BehaviourArray[0]);
}
```

=>

[image]

Comment: My behaviour array is made to put multiple component which have not the same type. I do it to disable those multiple component with a for loop so i can't do it with your methode. Actually i wanted to specifically store all those component in a Behaviour array to disable them.

Comment: @Koromire fait enough. All I'm saying is that in general you **can** use an array for the `out` parameter as long as the types match ... if they don't then yes you need to use something different due to strict typing in c# and in particular for generics